# Is it possible to generate a list through filtering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, filtering

I want to remove residue classes that are inside previous ones in a list through filtering.
I've tried to play with this problem for a couple days now and I can't get it to work.

I know that filtering works using a list, however I need to generate the list as well and I was hoping to do that through filtering.

I start with an empty list and only add to elements to it if they fit a certain criterion. This seems to work for the first couple of value of `h(z)` but fails for larger values and I'm confused as to why.

`[x,y]` represents the residue class of y modulo x.

At first I was interested in finding, for some power of two, `x=pow(2,w)`, all odd integers `y<x` such that `[x,y]>g(x,y)`. `g(x,y)` defined below.

Without discerning I get:

`[4,1],[8,5],[16, 1],[16,3],[16, 5],[16, 13],[32, 1],[32, 3],[32, 5],[32, 11],[32, 13],[32, 17],[32, 19],[32, 21],[32, 23],[32, 25],[32, 29]...`

***But I realized I don't need every output because many residue classes are inside a previous one.***

***As the list of tuples grows I need to eliminate the next residue classes to be added to the list if they are inside any of the residue classes already in the list.***

I don't need `[8,5]` because `5%4==1`, `[8,5]` is inside `[4,1]`, and similarly neither do I need `[16,1],[16,5]` or `[16,13]`.

`[4,1],[16,3],[32, 11],[32, 23],...`

Past `x=32`, I would need to eliminate odd integers `y%4==1,y%16==3,y%32==1,y%32==23`.

```py
def g(x,y):
    while x%2!=1:
        if (x%2==0 and y%2==1):
            x=(3/2)*x
            y=(3*y+1)/2
        while (x%2==0 and y%2==0):
            x=x/2
            y=y/2
    return [int(x),int(y)]

def h(z):
    requirements=[]
    for integer in range(1,z+1):
        x=pow(2,integer)
        residuelist=range(1,x+1)
        for z in requirements:
            for a,b in z:
                residuelist=filter(lambda x: x%a!=b,residuelist)
        residuelist=list(residuelist)
        for y in residuelist:
            if y%2==1:
                if [x,y]>g(x,y):
                    requirements.append((x,y))
    return requirements
```

`h` seems to work for `z=2,3,4`:

```py
h(2)
[[(4, 1)]]
```

```py
h(3)
[[(4, 1)]]
```

```py
h(4)
[[(4, 1)], [(16, 3)]]
```

but past `z=5`, something goes wrong

`h(5)` should be

```py
[[(4,1)],[(16,3)],[(32, 11)],[(32, 23)]]
```

but instead I get:

```py
[[(4, 1)], [(16, 3)], [(32, 1)], [(32, 5)], [(32, 11)], [(32, 13)], [(32, 17)], [(32, 21)], [(32, 23)], [(32, 25)], [(32, 29)]].
```

I don't know what's going on, because `h(4)` has the right tuples appended to it, so if the filter is working then `[(32,1)]` shouldn't be in there like many others? Something goes wrong in the iteration after two items are appended to `requirements`.

Comment: You're adding an extra level of lists. So intead of `[(4, 1)]` you're returning `[[(4, 1]]]`

Comment: It should be `requirements.append((x,y))`

Comment: I get TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Your code is really hard to understand with all those meaningless 1-letter function and variable names.

Comment: I tried that at first but h only works for h(2)

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Think of good names for your variables.

Comment: Sorry about that, I work in Mathematics that's probably where the 1-letter function syndrome comes from!

Comment: Yeah, this looks like code that a mathematician would write :)

Comment: Haha! I edited the code a little bit, maybe it's better :)

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the tuples in an extra level of lists. You don't need to wrap `(x, y)` in `[]` when appending, and then you only need one level of looping over `requirements`.

```
def h(z):
    requirements=[]
    for w in range(1,z+1):
        x=pow(2,w)
        v=range(1,x+1)
        for a, b in requirements:
            v=filter(lambda x: x%a!=b, v)
        v=list(v)
        for y in v:
            if y%2==1:
                if [x,y]>g(x,y):
                    requirements.append((x,y))
    return requirements
```

This wasn't a problem for `z=2, 3, 4` because the loop at the end only appended to `requirements` on the last iteration, so the `for z in requirements` loop never executed.

Comment: h(5) still produces the same output as above only the tuples aren't wrapped in `[]` square brackets, that was my first try when I wrote the code

Comment: I don't really understand the math of what you're doing. When `x=32`, `v = [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32]`. Is that correcet?

Comment: That's when `requirements = [(4, 1)]`. Add print statements to your code to see the variables at various places, to see where things aren't what you expect.

Comment: The only values that were filtered out were all 4n+1 values.

Comment: Yup! But I'm only interested in the `y` in `v= [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32]` that are odd `(%2==1)` and `[x,y]>g(x,y)` so it should be first v-odd = [ 3, 7,11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31] (all odd integers reduced) and then y=11,23 because those are the only values of y that satisfy [x,y]>g(x,y).

Comment: That's where I wrote the part `for y in v:` of the code